# How to format svg and xml like html in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open an svg or xml file and try to run "Format Document" I get the  message:

```
There is no document formatter for 'xml'-files installed.
```

To overcome that I usually just do "Language Mode" -> select HTML -> "Format Document".

**Is it possible to use the HTML formatter for XML and SVG?**

P.S I rather not install extensions.

Answer (score 28):

You should be able to override any extension to the language of your choice:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.xml": "html",
    "*.svg": "html",
}
```

Chuck that in your `settings.json` and you should be golden (although, I recommend not doing this, but it's your life)

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend doing this ?

Comment: This is the only thing that has enabled me to have prettier auto-format svg files, so I definitely recommend it. Thanks (even though you do not recommend it).

Comment: @SerdarSayın Because then you lose extension associations that would be able to interact with the filetype. You usually just want to install the formatter for the language/format you're working with. Given the "I rather not install extensions" goal though, this was pretty much the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you open an SVG file in vscode all the content is on a single line. If you just want to do a basic reformat for visual inspection or printing, you can generate a reformatted file using PowerShell, like so:

```
$svgOriginal = 'C:\yourfolder\yourfile.svg'
$svgFormatted = 'C:\yourfolder\yourfile.txt'
Get-Content $svgOriginal | format-xml | out-file $svgFormatted -Encoding utf8
```

Open the output file in vscode, set the language mode to HTML and (if necessary) turn on word wrap (Alt + Z)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using the [svgo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=1000ch.svgo) VSCode extension:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code with a test.svg file opened. The context menu is opened showing these options: 1. Minify current SVG file, and; 2. Prettify current SVG file.]

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: I'm not promoting this extension! I'm using it in my daily routine, and it's helping me in this situation.